# Fetch application properties from an embedded jar - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

I have a dependent jar file which I have added as a dependency. Is there a way to fetch use the application.properties file present in the dependent jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the property spring.config.location point to that application.properties
like

```
spring.config.location=classpath:com/company/whatever/application.properties
```

You can set spring.config.location on the command line when starting the application

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:com/company/whatever/application.properties
```

You find this explained in the [spring boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)